# Loop through a variable length loop to print values in a f string to send automated emails

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I'm trying to send emails with python 3 to let people know if the tasks are not completed based on an excel sheet. I stack the not completed tasks in a list and want to write a generic message using f strings.

```
for k in  range(2):
    action = []
    grade = sheet.cell_value(k+1,0)
    nom = sheet.cell_value(k+1,1)
    email = sheet.cell_value(k+1,3)
    document = sheet.cell_value(k+1,6)
    force = sheet.cell_value(k+1,9)
    medical = sheet.cell_value(k+1,10)
    transport = sheet.cell_value(k+1,8)
    ent = sheet.cell_value(k+1,7)
    
    if document == 1:
        action.append("Documents")

    if force == 18:
        action.append("PT")

    if medical == 12:
        action.append("Exam")

    if transport == 1:
        action.append("Transport")

    for item in action:
        print(item) 

    if len(action) > 0:
        message = f"Hello {grade} {nom}, \n" \
                  f'\n' \
                  f'Je vous écris, car certains éléments de votre dossier sont expirés. \n' \
                  f'En effet, le/les element(s) suivant(s) sont expiré(s) ou le seront sous peu: \n' \
                  f'\n' \
                  f'{action[1]}\n' \
                  f'{action[2]}\n' \
                  f'{action[3]}\n' \
                  f'\n' \
```

Obviously, since the list may have less than 3 elements I have an error popping up. How do I overcome this?

Comment: One way is to make sure that there are 3 elements in the action array by adding empty strings. That leaves you with some possible whitespace (empty lines) at the end. If you changed your actions to include the \n in the action that problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Use list slicing, when you use list slicing like `list[start:end]` you get a new list from length "start" to "end"-1.

```
task[1:4]
```

And if end is out of range, the error is gracefully handled automatically!

Or you can also argument unpacking (`print(*task[1:4],sep='\n')`) or looping on the slice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop, from:

```
tasks = []

for x in range(80)
    f'these tasks are not completed \n' \
    f'{task[1]} \n' \
    f'{task[2]} \n' \
    f'{task[3]} \n' \
```

to

```
tasks = []

for x in range(80)
    f'these tasks are not completed \n' \
    for t in task[1:]:
        f'{task} \n' \
```

Note that in python, indices start from `0`, rather than `1`. I believe what you're trying to do is:

```
tasks = []

for x in range(80)
    f'these tasks are not completed \n' \
    print('\n'.join(tasks))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a hammer to pull out a nail...

f-strings is a very nice tool, but you have just found a use case where you should not try to use them, at least as a whole.

I would use:

```
msg_txt = 'these tasks are not completed \n' + '\n'.join(t for t in tasks)
```

IMHO `join` and a generator comprehension is a better tool for handling *variable numbers* of elements.